# how to define unknown object into class python

Tags: python

I am getting an object(not defined in my code) from a SOAP request.
It prints out like this:

```
 Print(Person)

{
    'ID': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'FIRST_NAME': 'Qwe',
    'LAST_NAME': 'Qwe',
    'MIDDLE_NAME': 'Qwe',
    'TAB_NUM': '123456',
    'ORG_ID': '321'
}
```

I am trying to define it like this, but it doesn't do the job.

```
class PersonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = ''
        self.FIRST_NAME = ''
        self.LAST_NAME = ''
        self.MIDDLE_NAME = ''
        self.TAB_NUM = ''
        self.ORG_ID = ''

    def returnPerson(self):
        return (self)
```

This is a SOAP request and response:

```
POST /IntegrationService/IntegrationService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.56.3
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService/FindPeople"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FindPeople xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
      <sessionID>guid</sessionID>
      <lastname>string</lastname>
      <firstname>string</firstname>
      <middlename>string</middlename>
    </FindPeople>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FindPeopleResponse xmlns="http://parsec.ru/Parsec3IntergationService">
      <FindPeopleResult>
        <Person>
          <ORG_ID>guid</ORG_ID>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <ORG_ID>guid</ORG_ID>
        </Person>
      </FindPeopleResult>
    </FindPeopleResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

1. How to define a class in my code same as this object?
2. Is there a py module for this cases?

Comment: How are you making the SOAP request? Are you using some library for that? Can you show that code too?

Comment: `Person` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) a built in type of object in Python.

Comment: @AKX added to a question

Answer (score 4):

In case the SOAP response isn't fixed and you want the class to be generic enough, here are some solutions:

### Solution 1

Raw class

```
soap_raw = {
    'ID': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    'FIRST_NAME': 'Qwe',
    'LAST_NAME': 'Qwe',
    'MIDDLE_NAME': 'Qwe',
    'TAB_NUM': '123456',
    'ORG_ID': '321'
}


class SoapObject:
    def __init__(self, kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

soap_object = SoapObject(soap_raw)

print(f"{soap_object.ID=}")
print(f"{soap_object.FIRST_NAME=}")
print(f"{soap_object.LAST_NAME=}")
print(f"{soap_object.MIDDLE_NAME=}")
print(f"{soap_object.TAB_NUM=}")
print(f"{soap_object.ORG_ID=}")

print(f"Whole object: {soap_object.__dict__=}")
```

### Solution 2

Using [dataclasses.make_dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass)

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass
...
SoapObject = make_dataclass('SoapObject', soap_raw.keys())
soap_object = SoapObject(**soap_raw)
...
```

### Solution 3

The simplest and probably the best one. Thanks to **@AKX** for this idea! (See comments). Use [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace).

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
...
soap_object = SimpleNamespace(**soap_raw)
...
```

**Output** (applies to all 3 solutions)

```
soap_object.ID='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
soap_object.FIRST_NAME='Qwe'
soap_object.LAST_NAME='Qwe'
soap_object.MIDDLE_NAME='Qwe'
soap_object.TAB_NUM='123456'
soap_object.ORG_ID='321'
Whole object: soap_object.__dict__={'ID': '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 'FIRST_NAME': 'Qwe', 'LAST_NAME': 'Qwe', 'MIDDLE_NAME': 'Qwe', 'TAB_NUM': '123456', 'ORG_ID': '321'}
```

Comment: `types.SimpleNamespace` does the same thing.

Comment: Ohh okay so there's a builtin for this. I tried and it also worked, so it's better. Good to know, thank you for this info! :)

Comment: I updated the answer to show your idea as it seems the best option :)